# RXJS operators not working with firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'm using the RXJS operators with the firebase observable (distinct and filter).
this is my firebase tree
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkvUh.png).
this is my code:

```
  let places this.db.list(`users/${this.authProvider.getUID()}/visitedPlaces`,{
    query:{
      orderByChild:"googleId"
    }
  });
places.distinct((p)=>{ 
  console.log(p)
  return p.googleId;
}).
   subscribe((snap)=>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(snap,null,2))
    },(err)=>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err,null,2))
    },()=>{
      console.log("completed");
    });
```

I'm trying to distinct the firebase data according to googleId.
I didnt get any error but the distinct list is not working.

any help or reason for this? thanks.

Comment: Could you define "not working"? What is happening? Are any of your `console.log` statements executing?

Comment: both logs are returning a list. However, they are not distinct.

Comment: Could you show the output for `console.log(p)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(snap,null,2))`.

Comment: `[
  {
    "Latitude": 33.87628190799748,
    "Longitude": 35.53945333505702,
    "_isCurr": false,
    "googleId": ""
  },
  {...},{...}...] this log is the same for both

Comment: The log should be a single log entry for each item in `places`. It sounds like you are sending the whole array through the `distinct` operator rather than one element at a time.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to do `.map(...)` and remove duplicates normally.

Comment: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/distinct.html check this link please

Comment: why should i use the map operation since we have the distinct op.

Comment: You are using distinct on an array, not an object. If you want to use distinct on the objects within the array then you either need to emit the items separately through the stream or use the map operator and filter out duplicates using vanilla js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the `distinct` operator on an array rather than a stream of objects. So `p` is an array in your distinct operator rather than the object inside the array like you expect. You could do it with vanilla js in a `map` like so:

```js
Rx.Observable.of([
  { id: 1},
  { id: 2},
  { id: 1},
  { id: 3},
  { id: 2}
]).map(x => x.reduce((a, c) => {
   if (!a.some(y => y.id === c.id)) {
      a.push(c);
   }
   return a;
  }, [])
).subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Or you could expand the array using `flatMap` like so:

```js
Rx.Observable.of([
  { id: 1},
  { id: 2},
  { id: 1},
  { id: 3},
  { id: 2}
])
.flatMap(x => x)
.distinct(x => x.id)
.subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you its work. but the finale x that i need to display isn't async

Comment: so i can't use the async pipe to display the x value i need to stored in an array then i display it.

Comment: can u please explain how to sort the most duplicated number .so if number 2 is duplicated 5 times and number 1 is duplicated 2 times i need to display 2 the first number

Comment: @KhaledRamadan You can do any transformation on the data in the `map` operator. So if you are using the first solution then you just do `.sort(...)` on the array in the `map` operator. If you are using the second you will have to build the array in the subscribe. You could build it in order as it comes in or sort it in the completion callback.

Comment: @KhaledRamadan you can use the async pipe without it being async. As long as it is an observable you can use it.

Comment: Can u update the above example to be sort it according the most duplicate number. note:im using the second method

Comment: the order should be {2 1 3} or {1 2 3} because the id 1 and 2 are duplicated 2 times are equal

Comment: @KhaledRamadan since that is a different question than the one you originally asked above I think it would be better if you asked a new question on stack overflow on how to do that kind of sort.

Comment: this is the new question line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522124/how-to-sort-firebase-observable-list-based-on-the-duplicated-value-using-rxjs-op