# How to sort Firebase observable list based on the duplicated value using RXJS operators

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, rxjs

I'm using the rxjs operators to handle the firebase observable lists.
I need to sort distinct list  based on the duplicated value (certain id).

this is my code:

```
  this.places$
  .flatMap((x)=>{
    console.log(x)
    return x;
  })  
 .distinct((places:any)=>{ 
   console.log(places.googleId)
     return places.googleId;
  })
  .subscribe(snap=>{
    this.tempArray.push(snap);
  })
```

this is the log of (places.googleId)

[image]

so i need to sort this ids or the list according of the most duplicated number to be for example

```
    1-Eg9MZWJhbm9uLCBCZWlydXQ 
    2-EhZIYW1yYSwgQmVpcnV0LCBMZWJhbm9u
    3-ChIJR9lei8pAHxUREmilQojBkYc
```

Any help please,

thanks

Comment: Do you want it progressively sorted or just the final set sorted at completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach that I would take is to reduce the array using a counter sort. I'm assuming that you want just one value at the end that represents the sorted result of the whole stream. So I added the `last` operator to wait for completion.

If you wanted to do this with RxJs then you could use the `scan` operator to reduce the stream and then sort it in a `map` operator.

```js
function countDistinct(map, current) {
  let entry = map.get(current.id);
  if (!entry) {
    entry = {
      count: 0,
      data: current
    };
    map.set(current.id, entry);
  }
  entry.count++;
  return map;
}

function sortCountDescending(a, b) {
    return a.count < b.count ? 1
      : a.count > b.count ? -1
      : 0;
}

Rx.Observable.of([
  { id: 1},
  { id: 2},
  { id: 3},
  { id: 2},
  { id: 2},
  { id: 3}
])
.flatMap(x => x)
.scan(countDistinct, new Map())
.last() // remove this if you want a progressive result
.map(x => Array.from(x.values()).sort(sortCountDescending).map(x => x.data))
.subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Edit: You can use the `reduce` operator instead of `.scan(...).last()`. It basically does the same thing.

Comment: ` this.places$
  .flatMap((x)=>{
    console.log(x)
    return x;
  }) 
  .scan((map:any,current:any)=>{
    let entry = map.get(current.googleId);
    if (!entry) {
      entry = {
        count: 0,
        data: current
      };
      map.set(current.googleId, entry);
    }
    entry.count++;
    return map;
  }, new Map())
  .map(x => Array.from(x.values()).sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
    return a.count < b.count ? 1
    : a.count > b.count ? -1
    : 0;
  }).map((x:any) =>{
    console.log(x);
    return  x.data
    })
  )`

Comment: this  is my code is bade formatted, i got undefined in the subscribe function

Comment: some time it give the correct list sometime undefined

Comment: @KhaledRamadan you are missing a semi-colon after your `console.log(x)` in the `flatMap` operator. At least that is one issue.

Comment: Why not using reduce instead of scan+last?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo didn't realize reduce existed. I also wasn't sure if he wanted the intermediate values or just the final one.